# How do I cancel autocomplete with jqueryui?

Tags: jquery-ui, autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I have an input field which has an ajax data source autocomplete attached to it.

I have a keyup handler for the input field, which looks for someone pressing enter and when they do it triggers a click on the search button, which ajax loads some data in another div.

The problem is that if the person is quick and types and presses enter, the autocomplete still pops up.

I have tried the following:

- Adding `$('#autocomplete').autocomplete('close')`. This doesn't work, presumably because the autocomplete isn't open yet. If I type, wait for the autocomplete to come up, then press enter, it closes it correctly.
- Adding `$('#autocomplete').autocomplete('destroy')`. This works, but then if I go back to the field to try another search, the autocomplete no longer works.

So what I want is a way to cancel any pending requests and close the autocomplete if it's open, but without disabling or destroying it.

EDIT: Code sample (not my real code, just stubs to demonstrate the issue). Filename is scratch.php

```
<?php
// Stub for search results
if ($_GET['search'])
{
    print "Search results for ".$_GET['search']." here";
    exit();
}

// Simulated DB search
if ($_GET['term'])
{
    print '[{"label":"A 1"},{"label":"A 2"},{"label":"A 3"},{"label":"A 4"}]';
    exit();
}
?>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <link type="text/css" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.1/themes/redmond/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script language='javascript'>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#searchfor').on('keyup',function(e) {
            if (e.which == 13) $('#search').trigger('click');
        });
        $('#searchfor').autocomplete({
            source: "/scratch.php",
            minLength: 2,
            select: function( event, ui ) {
                $('#searchfor').val(ui.item.value);
                $('#search').trigger('click');
            }
        });
        $('#search').on('click',function() {
            try
            {
                // Cancel any pending autocompletes without destroying the autocomplete completely here.
                // This currently doesn't work
                $('#searchfor').autocomplete("close");
            }
            catch(e)
            {
                // Do nothing except prevent an error
            }
            $('#results').load('scratch?search='+encodeURIComponent($('#searchfor').val()));
        });
    });
    </script>
</head>
<input id='searchfor' /> <input id='search' type='button' value='search' />
<div id='results'></div>
</html>
```

Comment: Please provide code and/or [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) example

Comment: @Dom - code snippet added. I wasn't sure how to simulate the server side stuff with jsfiddle, so I just pasted a simplified code snippet that demonstrates the issue at hand.

Comment: what about increasing the delay and using the disable method instead of close method?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way to go about this is to make the `input` lose focus. You can do this by using [`.blur()`](http://api.jquery.com/blur/).  How about doing something like this:

JAVASCRIPT:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('#searchfor').on('keyup',function(e) {
            if (e.which == 13) $('#search').trigger('click');
               $('#searchfor').blur();
        });
        $('#searchfor').autocomplete({
            source: "/scratch.php",
            minLength: 2,
            select: function( event, ui ) {
                $('#searchfor').val(ui.item.value);
                $('#search').trigger('click');
            }
        });
        $('#search').on('click',function() {
            $('#results').load('scratch?search='+encodeURIComponent($('#searchfor').val()));
        });
    });
```

DEMO:
http://jsfiddle.net/dirtyd77/dMjRb/3/

Comment: That worked. I was expecting there to be something autocomplete-esque to call to cancel it, but this is fine. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In the current verion of jQuery UI you can use the search event to do some checks before the request to the data source is made

https://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#event-search

```js
    let autocompleteData = [
      "ActionScript",
      "AppleScript",
      "Asp",
      "BASIC",
      "C",
      "C++",
      "Clojure",
      "COBOL",
      "ColdFusion",
      "Erlang",
      "Fortran",
      "Groovy",
      "Haskell",
      "Java",
      "JavaScript",
      "Lisp",
      "Perl",
      "PHP",
      333333,
      222222,
      111111,
      123456
    ];
    
    $('input').autocomplete({
  source: autocompleteData,
  search:function(e,u){
   let value = e.target.value;
      // stops the event from continuing if value integer.
   if( Number.isInteger(parseInt(value)) ){
    e.preventDefault();
   }
  },
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<input type="text">
```

Answer (score 0):

assuming you have a one page app.

1. you can  wrap the input with

```js
<form onsubmit="return false;">...<form>
```

this will catch the enter key or any event that will trigger submit.

2. then, you can bind the submit event yourself and do:

```js
 $('input').blur().focus();
do something with $('input').val();
```